# Killing child process/task without killing main in Python using Pool Executor

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing, signals

I am trying to implement a method to force stop the child that have been started with **ThreadPoolExecutor** / **ProcessPoolExecutor**. I would like a cross platform implementation (Windows and Linux).

When the signal is triggered from main, the main process exits and I do **NOT** want that, only the child.

What is the correct way to force the child to quit? I do **NOT** want Events because in the following example I can have a while loop that never gets to **event.is_set()** again
eg:

```
while not event.is_set():
    # Do stuff
    while waiting_for_something:
        # Here is blocked
```

Here is the code I am using but I miss something and I don't know what:

```
import os
import signal
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
import time


def handler(signum, frame):
    print(signum, os.getpid())
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)


class asd:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, handler)
        while True:
            print('running thread', os.getpid())
            time.sleep(1)
            while True:
                print('running 2 ', os.getpid())
                time.sleep(1)
            print("after while")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = asd()
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    # pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    pool.submit(t1.run)

    print('running main', os.getpid())

    time.sleep(3)

    signal.raise_signal(signal.SIGBREAK)

    while True:
        print("after killing process")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are sending the signal to your main python process not to the children.

in order to send signals to your children you need their PID, which is not available using the concurrent module, instead you should use `multiprocess.Pool`, then you can get the PID of the children and send the signal to them using `os.kill`
just remember to eventually use `pool.terminate()` to guarantee resources cleanup.

```py
import os
import signal
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
import time
import psutil
import multiprocessing

def handler(signum, frame):
    print(signum, os.getpid())
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)


class asd:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, handler)
        while True:
            print('running thread', os.getpid())
            time.sleep(1)
            while True:
                print('running 2 ', os.getpid())
                time.sleep(1)
            print("after while")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = asd()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

    children = multiprocessing.active_children()
    res = pool.apply_async(t1.run)
    print('running main', os.getpid())

    time.sleep(3)

    for child in children:
        os.kill(child.pid,signal.SIGBREAK)

    while True:
        print("after killing process")
        time.sleep(1)
```

with result

```
running main 16860
running thread 14212
running 2  14212
running 2  14212
after killing process
after killing process
after killing process
```

Comment: Beautiful answer! I have changed the whole module to use **multiprocessing.Pool** instead of **concurrent.feature**. **EDIT**: If I kill one process from the pool, it will spawn a new one? Or just terminates the code inside and then returns to available process pool?

Comment: Also, is there a way to set process name using **apply_async**? Or any other method?

Comment: Adding a separate question on this: [Change name on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73752386/change-processs-name-from-multiprocess-pool-name-on-the-fly-or-get-pid-of-which)

Comment: @GeaniOrlando the pool automatically respawns any killed process but it will only execute functions that haven't started yet, the main benefit of the pool is that it automates the respawning and the work distribution among the numerous children, not give fine control on the behavior of one of the children, if you want finer control on the process you should use `multiprocessing.Process`, but make sure the child process is daemon=True, so it can be "garbage collected" like pools.

Comment: [Ahmed AEK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15649230/ahmed-aek) good explanation, thank you! So as you said, I cannot determine the PID of the process or to change the process name when I submit the function through **apply_async**, right?

Comment: @GeaniOrlando i never said you can't, it's just tedious, you can construct a `multiprocessing.queue` and submit the PID of the child on the queue once it starts executing the function, and the parent can know about it, and you can use something like [py-setproctitle](https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle) in the child to change the process name, which can be the first thing the function inside apply_async does before it starts executing the actual job. so there is always a way, it's just unnecessary extra work to avoid using `multiprocessing.Process`.

Comment: doing a lot of unnecessary extra work is dangerous, what if you were waiting on the child to send its PID and it crashed before it could send it ? the parent will be waiting on something that isn't going to happen and you will have to set-up a timeout system, and soon you'll have to invent a much larger system just to keep everything working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [pebble](https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/) which has been designed to solve this problem transparently for the User.

It provides `concurrent.futures` compatible APIs and allows to end a processing job either by cancelling the returned `Future` object or by setting a computing timeout.

```
import time
from pebble import ProcessPool
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError

TIMEOUT = 5

def function(sleep):
    while True:
        time.sleep(sleep)

with ProcessPool() as pool:
    future = pool.submit(function, TIMEOUT, 1)

assert isinstance(future.exception(), TimeoutError)
```

Note that you cannot stop executing threads in Python so only process pools can support such functionality.