# Change process's name from multiprocess.Pool name on the fly or get PID of which process is submitted

Tags: python, multiprocessing, rename, pid

Is there any method to change the process's name from a pool of processes on the fly? More exactly when submitting the execution through **apply_async**?

Mention: The subprocess is running in a while True loop, so it's alive.

Eg:

Change from:

```
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' pid=17680 parent=34172 started daemon>
```

to

```
<SpawnProcess name='Custom_Name' pid=17680 parent=34172 started daemon>
```

Or can I get the
**PID** of the which process from the pool has been assigned?

I know it can be changed through initializer when creating the pool but I want on the fly depending on the input I receive to set the name of it and then loop through **multiprocess.active_children** to determine the PID.

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot do this (atleast without a lot of hacking). Pool creates the subprocesses at the time it is created itself. Doing `apply_async` does not assign work to a worker process, it just puts it in a queue which the workers have access to. Communicating the process pid of the worker, which takes out a job from the queue, to the main process would be very inefficient. Your best bet would be to pass a shared dictionary and a unique identifier for each job. Then the pool workers can populate the dictionary with the key being the identifier and the value being their PID.

Comment: Please check my answer to your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73745355/killing-child-process-task-without-killing-main-in-python-using-pool-executor). Interrupting processes within Python standard Pools might rend them unstable as they are not designed for tolerating tampering with their internals.

Comment: I also asked on [discuss.python.org](https://discuss.python.org/t/thread-name-prefix-but-for-processpoolexecutor/31030).